# achieved the download functionality by hard coding the value for a csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I achieved the `download` functionality by hard-coding the value for a csv file but right now I am getting more values in `health` array which has different documents. In that, one document is pdf and another is txt.

If `health[0].mobileVersion` is pdf, I need to download the document as pdf. Similarly if `health[0].mobileVersion` is txt, I need to download the document as txt.

Can you guys tell me how to fix it.

My code below.

```js
$("#open1").click(function() {
  $("#win1").show().kendoWindow({
    width: "500px",
    height: "500px",
    modal: true,
    title: "Window 1"
  });
});

//debugger;

$("#open2").click(function() {
  $("#win2").show().kendoWindow({
    width: "500px",
    height: "500px",
    modal: true,
    title: "Window 2"
  }).data("kendoWindow").center();
});

$("#close2").click(function() {
  $("#win2").data("kendoWindow").close();
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pai-del-menu').hide();
  var cnt = 0;
  var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: [{
        FileName: '1 Download CSV (via btoa)',
        ThreeDots: 'ThreeDots1'
      }, {
        FileName: '2 Download CSV (via btoa)',
        ThreeDots: 'ThreeDots2'
      }, {
        FileName: '3 Download CSV (via btoa)',
        ThreeDots: 'ThreeDots3'
      }, {
        FileName: '4 Download CSV (via btoa)',
        ThreeDots: 'ThreeDots4'
      }, {
        FileName: '5 Download CSV (via btoa)',
        ThreeDots: 'ThreeDots4'
      }],
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            FileName: {
              type: "string"
            },
            ThreeDots: {
              type: "string"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      sort: {
        field: "FileName",
        dir: "asc"
      },
      pageSize: 10
    },
    height: 500,
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    selectable: true,
    filterable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [{
      field: "FileName",
      title: "File Name",

      template: function csvDownload(ev) {

        let model = {
          "addedByName": "lift",
          "mobileVersion": "Untitled-7.txt"
        }

        let skyCloudmageProfilePic = "mobilePicsDiplay";
        let extensionType = {
          ".pdf": "pdfProfilePic",
          ".ppt": "pptProfilePic",
          ".xls": "xlsProfilePic",
          ".xlsx": "xlsProfilePic",
          ".doc": "mobilePics",
          ".docx": "mobilePics",
          "newDocProfilePic": "doc",
          ".msg": "mailProfilePic"
        };
        let lastIndex = model.mobileVersion.lastIndexOf(".");

        skyCloudmageProfilePic = extensionType[model.mobileVersion.slice(lastIndex).toLowerCase()];
        if (typeof model.mobilePics != "undefined" && model.mobilePics != "") {
          skyCloudmageProfilePic = model.mobilePics;
        }
        if (typeof skyCloudmageProfilePic == "undefined") {
          skyCloudmageProfilePic = "newDocProfilePic";
        }
        let kendotxtMenu = "";
        if (model.isTigerDoc == true) //isTigerDocUploaded
        {
          kendotxtMenu = "mobilePicsDiplay";
        }
        if (model.isTigerDoc == true && model.TigerskyCloudD <= 0) //isTigerDocUploaded
        {

        }

        console.log("model.mobileVersion--->" + model.mobileVersion);
        // return "<span onclick=\"window.open('" + model.mobileVersion + "', 'popup', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no')\" class='" + skyCloudmageProfilePic + " displayInlineBlock " + kendotxtMenu + "'></span> <ul class='fileTypeHolder' id='fileTypeProfilePics' style='display: none;'><li class='fileTypeHolderTitle'>Tiger Document Type</li><li><span class='mobilePics displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType(doc)'></span></li> <li><span class='xlsProfilePic displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('xls')'></span></li> <li><span class='pptProfilePic displayInlineBlock'(click)='browseFileType('ppt')'></span></li> <li><span class='pdfProfilePic displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('pdf')'></span></li><li><span class='newDocProfilePic displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('newdoc')'></span></li><li><span class='mailProfilePic displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('mail')'></span></li><li class='fileTypeHolderCloseBtn'> <button id='CloseBtn' class='commonBtn'>Close</button></ul>";



        //return "testing" + that.FinancialDocuments.ImageType(model);

        let health = [{
            "addedByName": "player",
            "mobileVersion": "sa,ple.txt"
          },
          {
            "addedByName": "player",
            "mobileVersion": "sa,ple.pdf"
          }
        ]

        var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
        var data = new Blob([csv]);
        var a = $('<a/>', {
          class: 'sportsDataPlayer',
          download: 'download.csv',
          type: 'text/csv',
          href: URL.createObjectURL(data),
          html: ev.FileName
        });
        return "<span onclick=\"window.open('" + model.mobileVersion + "', 'popup', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no')\" class='" + skyCloudmageProfilePic + " displayInlineBlock " + kendotxtMenu + "'></span> <ul class='fileTypeHolder' id='fileTypeProfilePics' style='display: none;'><li class='fileTypeHolderTitle'>Tiger Document Type</li><li><span class='mobilePics displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType(doc)'></span></li> <li><span class='xlsProfilePic displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('xls')'></span></li> <li><span class='pptProfilePic displayInlineBlock'(click)='browseFileType('ppt')'></span></li> <li><span class='pdfProfilePic displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('pdf')'></span></li><li><span class='newDocProfilePic displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('newdoc')'></span></li><li><span class='mailProfilePic displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('mail')'></span></li><li class='fileTypeHolderCloseBtn'> <button id='CloseBtn' class='commonBtn'>Close</button></ul>" + a[0].outerHTML;
      }
    }, {
      field: "ThreeDots",
      title: "Last Name",
      template: "<span class='deleteRow'>ThreeDots</span>"
    }]
  }).data("kendoGrid");


  //var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
  //var data = new Blob([csv]);
  //debugger;
  //var a2 = document.getElementById("sportsDataPlayer");
  //alert("I am here");
  //a2.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);


  // grid.tbody.parents(".k-grid-content").eq(0).kendoScroller({ useOnDesktop: false });

  // Start by hiding the confirmation
  $('.testingConfirmation').hide();

  // Create a persistent value for the window
  var testingWindowVal;

  // Listen to save button click
  $("#save").click(function() {
    // Set the persistent value
    testingWindowVal = $("#fname").val();

    // Show the dialog
    if (testingWindowVal) {
      $('.testingConfirmation').show();
    }
  });

  // Listen to yes from the confirmation
  $('#deleteDocumentYes').click(function() {
    // Update necessary things
    grid.dataSource.add({
      "FileName": testingWindowVal,
      "ThreeDots": "Last Name"
    });
    $("#fname").val('');

    // Remove the value
    testingWindowVal = null;

    // Hide the dialog
    $('.testingConfirmation').hide();
  });

  // Listen to no from the confirmation
  $('#deleteDocumentNo').click(function() {
    // Remove the value
    testingWindowVal = null;

    // Reset the #fname
    $("#fname").val('');

    // Hide the dialog
    $('.testingConfirmation').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.pai-del-row {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pai-del-menu {
  padding: 4px;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#runningDocumentsPopup .sports {
  position: relative;
}

.sports .kPopupConfirmationBox {
  display: block;
  z-index: 3;
  left: calc(50% - 175px);
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
}

.sports {
  display: block;
}


/* Style for confirmation dialog */

.testingConfirmation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.322/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.322/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.322/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a id="open1">Open first Window</a>

<div id="win1" style="display:none">
  <p>First Window</p>
  <input type="file" name="batchFile" id="batchFile" title="Select file" />

  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
  <button type="button" id="save">save</button>


  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div id="grid"></div>
  <div class="pai-del-menu">Delete</div>


  <div class="testingConfirmation">
    <div class="kendopobUpBox kendoWindow kPopupConfirmationBox">
      <div class="row kendoPopUpGridCollection kendoPopUpContent lineHeightInputs">
        <div class="kendoContent">Are you sure you want to delete the selected document</div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearFloat"></div>

      <div class="row kendoPopUpFooter textAligncenterImp">
        <button class="commonBtn" type="button" id="deleteDocumentYes">Yes</button>
        <button class="clearBtn" type="button" id="deleteDocumentNo">No</button>
      </div>

      <div class="clearFloat"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="sports">
    <div class="kendopobUpBox kendoWindow kPopupConfirmationBox">
      <div class="row kendoPopUpGridCollection kendoPopUpContent lineHeightInputs">
        <div class="kendoContent">Are you sure you want to upload file</div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearFloat"></div>

      <div class="row kendoPopUpFooter textAligncenterImp">
        <button class="commonBtn" type="button" id="playerDocumentOk" (click)="uploadFile($event,document.value)">OK</button>
        <button class="clearBtn" type="button" id="playerDocumentCancel" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      <div class="clearFloat"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/fe5en27q/

Comment: What is passed to `Blob()` when file that should be downloaded is a `.pdf`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` to iterate `health` array, set `.type` of `Blob` to `"text/plain"` or `"application/pdf"`.

```
let health =[{ "addedByName":"player", "mobileVersion":"sa,ple.txt" },
             { "addedByName":"player", "mobileVersion":"sa,ple.pdf" }
            ];

let types = ["text/plain", "application/pdf"];

let downloads = health.map(function(version) {
                  let ext = version.mobileVersion.replace(/.*(?=\.\w+)/, "");
                  let mimeType = types.filter(function(type) {
                                   return type.indexOf(ext) > -1
                                 });
                  let data = new Blob([/*  Blob data */], {
                               type: mimeType
                             });
                  return $("<a>", {
                           "class": "sportsDataPlayer",
                           download: ev.FileName + ext,
                           type: mimeType,
                           href: URL.createObjectURL(data),
                           html: ev.FileName
                         });
                });
```

Comment: Hey can you explain more in detail....so that in future I will implement another functionality using map

Comment: Check the file extension using `RegExp`, set `Blob` `.type` to the matched extension MIME type stored in an array.

Comment: What's the use of passing version parameter inside map method

Comment: `version` is the current object of the array.  `version.mobile` should be `version.mobileVersion`. `.map()` iterates each element of an array.

Comment: Is there any easy way to remember expression... how you regular expression easily??

Comment: You could alternatively use `String.prototype.indexOf()` or `.split()`. What we are trying to achieve is get the extension of the file name in the string, that is `.txt` or `.pdf`. The `RegExp` replaces characters followed by `"."` and one or more words. That could be an issue if the file name contains more than one `"."` character.

Comment: How you guys know you can use method.... I was thinking but not sure which method to use....is there any technique when to use map method for iteration....it would be great if you let me know...so that in future I will do it myself

Comment: The process could be composed several different ways. If you continue writing your own code you should be able to determine or choose which methods to use for the specific requirement

Comment: hey but for this one how did you choose map method ??

Comment: `health` array contains two elements

Comment: how did you find out this regular expression will work replace(/.*(?=\.\w+)/, ""); and can you update comments...it will help me in understanding more...

Comment: The `RegExp` is intended to match all characters followed by `".ext"` where `"ext"` is for example `".txt"` or `".pdf"`, replace the characters with an empty string, leaving `".ext"`

Comment: But how you find which regular expression will work...since lots of symbols are there right??

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: can you update the code with comments its hard to understand :(

Comment: can you tell me why you are using greater than 1 at this line types.filter(function(type) {
                                   return type.indexOf(ext) > -1
                                 });

Comment: hey I tried integrate your code in my codebase which is typescript...I am getting an error like this [ts]
Argument of type '{ type: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BlobPropertyBag'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
(property) type: string[]     at this line  ----------------> var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
         let data = new Blob([csv], {type: mimeType});